# Postgresql 14 Performance regression versus PG13

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

I migrated a database from Postgresql 13 to Postgresql 14 recently, and I saw a x2 execution time in a specific case which I can't understand.
The issue has been seen on a Postgres on Linux, and I reproduced the following example on macOS with Postgres installed through `brew`

Here is how to reproduce the setup:

```sql
-- DB Setup
CREATE DATABASE pg_regression_test;

-- Connect to the new DB

-- Table: units
CREATE TABLE units
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Table: events
-- Events agr global, and the value is a payload/metadata JSONB field where you can have
-- the id of a related unit (or seomething else). If it's a unit, then you have a value
-- value = {'unit_id': 123}
CREATE TABLE events
(
    action    VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    value     JSONB,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX events_action_idx ON events (action);

CREATE INDEX events_unit_id_idx ON events ((value ->> 'unit_id')) WHERE (value ? 'unit_id');

-- Materialized view: daily_unit_events
-- Answers: how many similar actions have been made on this unit that day?
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW daily_unit_events AS
SELECT s.id         AS unit_id,
       s.action,
       s.dt,
       SUM(s.count) AS count
FROM (
         WITH t AS (
             SELECT events.value ->> 'unit_id'                  AS unit_id,
                    events.action,
                    DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE AS dt,
                    1                                           AS count
             FROM events
             WHERE events.value ? 'unit_id'
             GROUP BY events.value ->> 'unit_id',
                      events.action,
                      (DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE)
         )
         SELECT units.id,
                t.action,
                t.dt,
                SUM(t.count) AS count
         FROM units
                  JOIN t ON units.id::TEXT = t.unit_id
         GROUP BY units.id, t.action, t.dt
     ) s
GROUP BY s.id, s.action, s.dt;

CREATE INDEX daily_unit_events_unit_id_idx ON daily_unit_events (unit_id);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX daily_unit_events_unique_idx ON daily_unit_events (unit_id, action, dt);

-- Data generation
-- Insert 100k units
INSERT INTO units (id)
SELECT i
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100000) s(i);

-- Insert 1M events with a unit_id in the value. Around 20 kind of events. Est: 42s
INSERT INTO events (action, value, timestamp)
SELECT LEFT(MD5(((RANDOM() * 20)::INT)::TEXT), 12)                     AS action,
       JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('unit_id', (RANDOM() * 100000)::INT)         AS value,
       (NOW() - (INTERVAL '1 day' * (RANDOM() * 720)::INT))::TIMESTAMP AS timestamp
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000) s(i);

-- Insert 150k events without a unit_id in the value. Just to be on par with real data.
-- Around 20 kind of other events, distinct from the previous ones. Est: 3s
INSERT INTO events (action, value, timestamp)
SELECT LEFT(MD5(((RANDOM() * 20)::INT + 20)::TEXT), 12)                AS action,
       '{}'::JSONB                                                     AS value,
       (NOW() - (INTERVAL '1 day' * (RANDOM() * 720)::INT))::TIMESTAMP AS timestamp
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 150000) s(i);
```

The issue comes from the materialized view `daily_unit_events`, where the refresh is two times as long on PG14 versus PG13:

```sql
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY daily_unit_events;

-- With test data, once first run is done. (first run is ~2x longer than follow ups)
-- PG 13.7:
--   - completed in 13 s 340 ms
--   - completed in 13 s 436 ms
--   - completed in 12 s 971 ms
--   - completed in 12 s 976 ms
-- PG 14.3:
--   - completed in 24 s 253 ms
--   - completed in 19 s 462 ms
--   - completed in 21 s 941 ms
--   - completed in 24 s 213 ms
```

If you take the query used for the materliazed view, you can see the same behavior:

```sql
SELECT s.id         AS unit_id,
       s.action,
       s.dt,
       SUM(s.count) AS count
FROM (
         WITH t AS (
             SELECT events.value ->> 'unit_id'                  AS unit_id,
                    events.action,
                    DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE AS dt,
                    1                                          AS count
             FROM events
             WHERE events.value ? 'unit_id'
             GROUP BY (events.value ->> 'unit_id'), events.action,
                      (DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE)
         )
         SELECT units.id,
                t.action,
                t.dt,
                SUM(t.count) AS count
         FROM units
                  JOIN t ON units.id::TEXT = t.unit_id
         GROUP BY units.id, t.action, t.dt
     ) s
GROUP BY s.id, s.action, s.dt;

-- With test data (unit):
-- PG 13.7:
--   - completed in 3 s 355 ms (execution: 3 s 254 ms, fetching: 101 ms)
--   - completed in 3 s 272 ms (execution: 3 s 234 ms, fetching: 38 ms)
--   - completed in 3 s 331 ms (execution: 3 s 303 ms, fetching: 28 ms)
--   - completed in 3 s 332 ms (execution: 3 s 307 ms, fetching: 25 ms)
-- PG 14.3:
--   - completed in 11 s 436 ms (execution: 11 s 392 ms, fetching: 44 ms)
--   - completed in 14 s 520 ms (execution: 14 s 487 ms, fetching: 33 ms)
--   - completed in 12 s 83 ms (execution: 12 s 39 ms, fetching: 44 ms)
--   - completed in 11 s 345 ms (execution: 11 s 314 ms, fetching: 31 ms)
```

By `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`'inig the previous query, you get (took the third run to avoid startup issues):

- PG13:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=5274537.33..13620413.68 rows=5750000 width=53) (actual time=3215.938..4877.993 rows=999667 loops=1)
  Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
  Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
  ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=5274537.33..12398538.68 rows=57500000 width=29) (actual time=3215.929..4213.314 rows=999667 loops=1)
        Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
        Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=5274537.33..11344372.02 rows=47916666 width=29) (actual time=3215.921..3746.462 rows=999667 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
              ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=5273537.31..5812599.80 rows=23958333 width=29) (actual time=3111.237..3363.517 rows=333222 loops=3)
                    Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
                    ->  Sort  (cost=5273537.31..5333433.14 rows=23958333 width=25) (actual time=3111.218..3177.549 rows=333222 loops=3)
                          Sort Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 15016kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10256kB
                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 11952kB
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=5220.27..617292.54 rows=23958333 width=25) (actual time=90.272..2938.759 rows=333222 loops=3)
                                Merge Cond: (((units.id)::text) = ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)))
                                Buffers: shared hit=2985364
                                ->  Sort  (cost=5218.20..5322.36 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=58.281..63.245 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: ((units.id)::text)
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3257kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=278
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2055kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2278kB
                                      ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using units_pkey on units  (cost=0.29..2020.96 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=0.068..26.356 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                            Heap Fetches: 0
                                            Buffers: shared hit=278
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=2.07..132774.67 rows=115000 width=53) (actual time=0.466..2643.878 rows=993712 loops=3)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=2985086
                                      ->  Group  (cost=2.07..131337.17 rows=115000 width=53) (actual time=0.450..2228.330 rows=993712 loops=3)
                                            Group Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=2985086
                                            ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=2.07..122951.83 rows=1003045 width=49) (actual time=0.447..1899.806 rows=994041 loops=3)
                                                  Sort Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                                  Presorted Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text))
                                                  Full-sort Groups: 27025  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2985086
                                                  Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 26566  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                                  Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 27000  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                                  ->  Index Scan using events_unit_id_idx on events  (cost=0.42..73820.46 rows=1003045 width=49) (actual time=0.101..1184.753 rows=994056 loops=3)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=2985028
Planning Time: 0.435 ms
Execution Time: 4974.368 ms
```

- PG14

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=5272591.23..13616435.63 rows=5748600 width=53) (actual time=9223.276..11004.233 rows=999671 loops=1)
  Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
  Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
  ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=5272591.23..12394858.13 rows=57486000 width=29) (actual time=9223.269..10326.712 rows=999671 loops=1)
        Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
        Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=5272591.23..11340948.13 rows=47905000 width=29) (actual time=9223.261..9827.932 rows=999671 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
              ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=5271591.21..5810522.46 rows=23952500 width=29) (actual time=8045.307..8301.748 rows=333224 loops=3)
                    Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                    Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
                    ->  Sort  (cost=5271591.21..5331472.46 rows=23952500 width=25) (actual time=8045.284..8115.779 rows=333224 loops=3)
                          Sort Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 17824kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10640kB
                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8760kB
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=5220.24..616523.46 rows=23952500 width=25) (actual time=739.098..7296.621 rows=333224 loops=3)
                                Merge Cond: (((units.id)::text) = ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)))
                                Buffers: shared hit=3002075
                                ->  Sort  (cost=5218.20..5322.36 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=571.336..577.142 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: ((units.id)::text)
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3613kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=278
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2107kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1870kB
                                      ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using units_pkey on units  (cost=0.29..2020.96 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=0.063..15.491 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                            Heap Fetches: 0
                                            Buffers: shared hit=278
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=2.05..132122.18 rows=114972 width=53) (actual time=0.434..6303.380 rows=999327 loops=3)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=3001797
                                      ->  Group  (cost=2.05..130685.03 rows=114972 width=53) (actual time=0.425..5882.899 rows=999327 loops=3)
                                            Group Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=3001797
                                            ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=2.05..122329.63 rows=999082 width=49) (actual time=0.423..5532.640 rows=999650 loops=3)
                                                  Sort Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                                  Presorted Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text))
                                                  Full-sort Groups: 27020  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 28kB  Peak Memory: 28kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=3001797
                                                  Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 26999  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 28kB  Peak Memory: 28kB
                                                  Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 27023  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 28kB  Peak Memory: 28kB
                                                  ->  Index Scan using events_unit_id_idx on events  (cost=0.42..73541.97 rows=999082 width=49) (actual time=0.049..1407.220 rows=999666 loops=3)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=3001739
Planning Time: 0.269 ms
Execution Time: 11103.528 ms
```

What could be the cause of this performance regression?
Thank you!

Comment: `explain (analyze, buffers)` please; the estimated plan is useless.

Comment: That is a striking difference, but I can't reproduce it when running the query by hand.  What is your OS?  How did you install both versions?  What happens if you disable parallel query (`set max_parallel_workers_per_gather TO 0;`)

Comment: I run postgres on macOS
`brew services stop postgresql@13 && brew unlink postgresql@13 && brew link postgresql@14 && brew services start postgresql@14`
It's especially because we had this issue in production on Linux that I tried to reproduce it locally. So, not platform specific.

Setting the max_parrallel_workers_per_gather on PG1 changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you should increase the `work_mem` to allow sorting to happen in RAM. Both versions execute something like

```
Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 17824kB
```

In addition, version 13 seems to be able to compete Merge Join with nearly 10x the performance compared to version 14.

If you can afford to increase `work_mem` to 32 MB, it should improve the performance. I think the default might be 16 MB and if some of the work can fit into that with version 13 but version 14 needs e.g. 10% more RAM for the same task, it might explain the difference in performance because version 14 will then need to do more IO to reduce memory usage during sorting.

The behavior of `work_mem` changed (at least?) between PostgreSQL 12 and 13 so it wouldn't be that big a surprise if it had changed again.

Comment: Also, we had a problem with one database after upgrading from version 12 to 14 that the performance was really low until `vacuum analyze` was executed successfully. For some reason, the statistics were off a lot by default. The upgrade was done with `pg_upgrade` so it might have something to do with the results.